# what is the next after comma in $('.elem',elem)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using code like `$('.elem',elem)`, `$('.elem',elem).tabs()`.

`$(".elem")` is used to select elements with that class.

But what is the next after comma? What is the use of it?

Comment: It's the [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), equivelant to `$(elem).find('.elem');`

Comment: I've been using jQuery for almost 2 years now but didn't paid much attention into that. :) +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$('.elem',elem)` is `$(elem).find('.elem')`. In fact, that's what jQuery does with it under the covers. It finds all elements with class `"elem"` that are descendants of the `elem` element.

This is covered in [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). It's well worth spending an hour just reading that from beginning to end. There are all sorts of useful things in there that aren't well known. :-) (I'm not saying this is one of them [I'm not a fan of it myself, some folks are], just that generally there are lots of useful things in there.)

Comment: seems like there is no advantage to use context over find(), is it true?

Comment: @roasted: Right. *Well*, I suppose some would point out that it's fewer characters. :-) But when I say "that's what jQuery does with it under the covers" I mean exactly that: It literally detects that you've done `$('.elem', elem)` and passes off to `$(elem).find('.elem')`. So the `$('.elem', elem)` form just adds another function call (not that that really matters).

Answer (score 4):

This is the context into which the search is done.

It's the same than

```
$(elem).find('.elem')
```

See [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter passed to the jQuery function defines the scope or context of the first selector.

It tells jQuery to find all elements with a class of `elem` within the element supplied in the second parameter.  Elements with a class of `.elem` outside of `elem` would not be selected.

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="included">
    <input/>
    <input/>
</div>
<div id="excluded">
    <input/>
    <input/>
</div>
```

These selectors produce the following output:

```
console.log($("input", "#included").length); //2 only those inside included
console.log($("input").length); //4 all inputs
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LE6eE/

Comment: I've used selector with .find() method. but $(".elem",elem) is working well than .find(). So is the find() method is useful or not?

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything the context specifier can't do that find does.  I guess `find` is a bit more intuitive and easier to read.